# C# -How to give a list of all animals in chosen by id shelter with this api route`/api/shelters/<id>/animals`

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I need a list of all the animals names within a shelter. The shelter is chosen by id, so in this case 1. 
The api-route should be **/api/shelters/< id >/animals**.

If the chosen id isn't a shelter it should be a 404 .

```
// specific list of animals in the chosen shelter -by Id-
public IActionResult animals(int ShelterId) {
    var infoAnimals = ShelterDatabase.Shelter.Animals;
    return new ObjectResult(infoAnimals);
}

var shelter = new Shelter.Shared.Shelter()
{
    ShelterId = 1,
    Name = "Our shelter"
};

shelter.Animals = new List<Animal>
{
    new Cat{ Id = 1,Name = "Poes",DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2000, 02, 14),IsChecked = true,KidFriendly = false,Since = DateTime.Now,Declawed = true,Race = "Hairless Sphynx"},
    new Cat{ Id = 2,Name = "Kity",DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2000, 02, 14),IsChecked = true,KidFriendly = false,Since = DateTime.Now,Declawed = true,Race = "Hairless Sphynx"},
    new Cat{ Id = 3,Name = "wietel",DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2000, 02, 14),IsChecked = true,KidFriendly = false,Since = DateTime.Now,Declawed = true,Race = "Hairless Sphynx"},
    new Dog{ Id = 4,Name = "Felix",DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2000, 02, 14),IsChecked = true,KidFriendly = true,Since = DateTime.Now,Barker = true,Race = "Golden Retriever"},
    new Dog{ Id = 5,Name = "peppa",DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2000, 02, 14),IsChecked = true,KidFriendly = true,Since = DateTime.Now,Barker = true,Race = "Danish Dog"},
};
```

Comment: What part are you struggling with ?

Comment: I already found how I could show info about the different shelters with the route api/shelters  , but now with the id and another word in the route I'm stuck

Comment: Do you use .net or .net Core?

Comment: add the content of `webapiconfig.cs` file please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

The default routing scheme will be like this: `"[controller]/[action]/{id}"`,

So for every action in the controller there will be a separate route

In your case `/api/shelters/< id >/animals`, your route misses the action or they are in incorrect order

I would do it like this:

```
//api/shelters/0
[HttpGet("[controller]/{id}")] 
public IActionResult sherlter(int ShelterId) {
    var shelter = ShelterDatabase.Shelter;
    return new ObjectResult(shelter);
}

//api/shelters/animals/0
[HttpGet("[controller]/[action]/{id}")] 
public IActionResult animals(int ShelterId) {
    var infoAnimals = ShelterDatabase.Shelter.Animals;
    return new ObjectResult(infoAnimals);
}
```

(Use annotations: `[HttpGet]` for .net core or `[Route]` for .net framework)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look similar to this:

```
public IActionResult animals(int ShelterId)
{
    var shelters = ShelterDatabase.Shelter;  // this should be collection of shelters
    var shelter = shelters.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.ShelterId == ShelterId);
    if (shelter == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var animals = shelter.Animals;

    return new ObjectResult(animals);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you must specify the request method allowed (Get, Post, Put, Delete) and give it a route prefix/suffix and route name (animals).

```
// specific list of animals in the chosen shelter -by Id-
[HttpGet("{id}/animals")]
public IActionResult animals(int ShelterId) {
    var infoAnimals = ShelterDatabase.Shelter.Animals;
    return new ObjectResult(infoAnimals);
}
```

Comment: The only person to have read the question and delivered what was being asked for